# Converter Double para String MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, conversão-de-tipo

Possuo um campo `Double` em uma *collection* no MongoDB e gostaria de trocar este campo em toda coleção para `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//inteiro para string
db.temp.find({name: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    db.temp.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {name: x.name.toString()}});
});

//string para data
db.temp.find({name: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    db.temp.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {name: ISODate(x.name}});
});

//string para inteiro
db.temp.find({name: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    db.temp.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {name: NumberInt(x.name)}});
});
```

Fonte: http://codigosimples.net/2016/03/05/conversao-de-tipos-com-mongodb/